# rbenv-vars working on console but not on web application

Tags: ruby, nginx, puma, rbenv, rbenv-vars

I'm using Ruby 2.7.2, Rails 6.0.3, Debian 10 with Nginx & Puma.

I'm facing an issue with the web application.

The environment variable is loaded by the `rails console` but not by the web application.

I created the `.rbenv-vars` file in the project directory and I checked that it is properly loaded:

```
rbenv vars

export FOO=BAR
```

I checked on the console and the env variable is returning "BAR".

```
rails c -e production
puts "FOO VARIABLE: #{ENV['FOO']}"
=> "BAR"
```

But when I'm checking the log, I see the `ENV['FOO']` is returning `nil`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :show_env_variables

  def show_env_variables
    puts "FOO VARIABLE: #{ENV['FOO']}"
  end
end
```

Do you know why the env variables are not being read by the web app?

This is my `puma.rb`

```
#!/usr/bin/env puma

directory '/home/deploy/apps/app_name/current'
rackup "/home/deploy/apps/app_name/current/config.ru"
environment 'staging'

tag ''

pidfile "/home/deploy/apps/app_name/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "/home/deploy/apps/app_name/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state"
stdout_redirect '/home/deploy/apps/app_name/shared/log/puma_access.log', '/home/deploy/apps/app_name/shared/log/puma_error.log', true


threads 0,16


bind 'unix:///home/deploy/apps/app_name/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock'

workers 0

restart_command 'bundle exec --keep-file-descriptors puma'

prune_bundler

on_restart do
  puts 'Refreshing Gemfile'
  ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = ""
end
```

This is the conf I have on `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.com`

```
server {
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

  listen 443;
  listen [::]:443;
  server_name domain.com;
  root /home/deploy/apps/app_name/current/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma_app_name;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

  error_page 500 502 504 /500.html;
  error_page 503 @503;

  location @puma_app_name {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
      proxy_pass http://puma_app_name;
    # limit_req zone=one;
    access_log /home/deploy/apps/app_name/shared/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /home/deploy/apps/app_name/shared/log/nginx.error.log;
  }

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location = /50x.html {
    root html;
  }

  location = /404.html {
    root html;
  }

  location @503 {
    error_page 405 = /system/maintenance.html;
    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
    }
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
  }

  if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$ ){
    return 405;
  }

  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
    return 503;
  }
}

server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name domain.com;
  rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}
```